# How do I call .showDialog() from a dynamically loaded class

Tags: android, dialog, dynamic-controls

I am creating a home automation app that has allows plugin views.  I have been able to create a class as a sample plugin in a separate project (apk):

```
public class MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn extends Button implements IRDroidInterface{
    Context mContext;
    public MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        setText("I was loaded dynamically! (1)");
        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                    // how do I show the dialog from here? 
                Activity.showDialog(1);
            }}  
                );
    }
    public Dialog buildConfigDialog(int ID){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setMessage("Click the Button...(1)")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
               }           
           });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

I can load this class at run time and create an instance of it:

```
        try {
        final File filesDir = this.getFilesDir();
        final File tmpDir = getDir("dex", 0);
        final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader( filesDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/testloadclass.apk",
                tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(),
                null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
        final Class<View> classToLoad = 
                (Class<View>) classloader.loadClass("com.strutton.android.testloadclass.MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn");
        mybutton = (View) classToLoad.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);
        mybutton.setId(2);
        main.addView((View)mybutton);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setContentView(main);
}
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return ((IRDroidInterface) mybutton).buildConfigDialog(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want the plugin to be able to show a configuration dialog.  Is there a way I can pass the Activity object to this class so it can use .showDialog(ID).  This would be ideal so that the dialog life cycle can be managed properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you do something like this?

```
public class MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn extends Button implements IRDroidInterface{
    Activity mContext;
    public MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn(Activity context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        ...
        setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                mContext.showDialog(1);
            }}  

        );

.....
}
```

When you're creating this class, you're already passing `Activity` into this class - so just use it.

Comment: I am passing `Context` into this class.  An activity is a context, but unfortunately a context is not an activity.  `Error:  
The method showDialog(int) is undefined for the type Context MyTestClass_IRDroidUIPlugIn.java /testloadclass/src/com/strutton/android/testloadclass line 22 Java Problem`

Comment: @cstrutton: If you notice in my answer, I changed the parameter type in the constructor and member variable from Context to Activity.  When you're passing Context into the constructor, you're actually passing the activity - just declare it as such and use it.  You would need to change the abstract superclass as well for this, of course.

Comment: Thanks again.  It seems I have another problem tied to the same code.  I was loading the interface twice (once in the main code and once in the plugin).  Once I figured that out, the rest started to work. One thing though: I edited the above code to cast activity to Context.  Eclipse was complaining.  I did this as my test class extends Button.  This is acceptable?

Comment: @cstrutton How were you doing the cast?  Maybe you were just missing a pair of parentheses.

Comment: My mistake was making my interface a comon file to both projects (main app and plugin) instead creating a library project and referencing it in both.  Near as I can figure, I was loading the interface twice and I was getting cast exceptions.  I haven't had the chance to test this but I am sure this is the case.  I have to say I am very pleased with the Android framework.  Every thing I try just works.  Then when something doesn't I get so frusterated because I am sure I just missed a bracket or a comma somewhere.